# Firebase database works only when activity is closed

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an app with Firebase database. I am trying to write to the database, but the data is not being updated until activty closes.
In this example, only when the screen is closed that the database is updated.

```
class YouTubeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val database: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube)

        testeButton.setOnClickListener {
            database.child("teste").child("estado").setValue("testing")
        }

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        database.child("teste").child("estado").setValue("onStart")
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        database.child("teste").child("estado").setValue("onPause")
    }
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        database.child("teste").child("estado").setValue("onStop")
    }
}
```

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Are you sure it is only working when you close activity?
Because the code you have mentioned is all having value update for same keys. So if you are checking in database after closing activity, it will show "onStop" for "estado" key.

Comment: The code looks fine, and should write on each of the lifecycle methods. You might want to put a breakpoint in each of those methods, step through it in the debugger, and check the logcat output for any relevant error messages.